# Import submodule functions into the parent namespace

Tags: python, optimization, namespaces, python-import, directory-structure

I have a package of commonly used utility functions which I import into tons of different projects, using different parts.  [I'm following patterns that I've seen in `numpy`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/__init__.py#L158-L188), by doing things like:

````
utils/
    __init__.py
        ```
        from . import math
        from . import plot
        ```
    math/
        __init__.py
            ```
            from . import core
            from . core import *
            from . import stats
            from . stats import *
            __all__ = []
            __all__.extend(core.__all__)
            __all__.extend(stats.__all__)
            ```
        core.py
            ```
            __all__ = ['cfunc1', 'cfunc2']
            def cfunc1()...
            def cfunc2()...
            ```
        stats.py
            ```
            __all__ = ['sfunc1', 'sfunc2']
            def sfunc1()...
            def sfunc2()...
            ```
    plot/
        __init__.py
````

The nice thing about this structure is I can just call the submodule functions from the higher level namespaces, e.g. `utils.math.cfunc1()` and `utils.math.sfunc2()`.
The issue is: both `core` and `stats` take a long time to import, so I don't want to automatically import them both from `math.__init__`.

**Is there any way to *not* import both `stats` and `core` by default, and instead use something like `import utils.math.core`, but still have the functions in `core` end up in the `math` namespace?**  i.e. be able to do:

```
import utils.math.core
utils.math.cfunc1()
```